Automatically redirect user to their SAML login page
I'm using WSO2 IdentityServer v7.0.0.
I set up SAML integration for a client who uses Azure Entra. I can add their login link to the default username/password login in the Login Flow screen, but they do not want to use that page and do not want their name displayed on it.
Is there a way to create a link that takes users to their Azure login page while still using WSO2? In short, do not put their SAML login link on the login page, but somehow redirect to it automatically.
